# Stream was not Readable for PayPalRest API

Tags: paypal

This occurs in the Sandbox or production.  In the sandbox if I enter in a Visa of 4111111111111111 with a code, and exp date... When I hit the payment.Creat(token) line, an exception is thrown, "Stream was not readable".  If I put in some other CC number like 4234567890123456 the payment works fine.  In production, if I use that 4234...  I get the stream was not readable error.  I understand test cards do not always work, but I expect back a Credit Card invalid response.  The problem I have is that some of my customers are getting the stream error....  If I put in a real CC in production, it works fine.. but if i change 1 number I get the invalid card error....  So sometimes it sends it back correctly, other times it is the Stream error...  I recently update the package to latest and greatest API using Nuget, but does anyone else have any suggestions?

Here is my relevant code
                try
            {
                var token = GetAPIToken();

```
            var creditCard = new CreditCard();
            creditCard.number = req.CardNumber;
            creditCard.expire_month = req.ExpMonth;
            creditCard.expire_year = req.ExpYear;
            creditCard.first_name = req.FirstName;
            creditCard.last_name = req.LastName;
            creditCard.type = req.CardType;
            creditCard.payer_id = req.UserId.ToString();
            creditCard.cvv2 = req.SecurityCode;

            creditCard.billing_address = new Address()
            {
                line1 = req.Address1,
                city = req.City,
                state = req.State,
                postal_code = req.ZipCode,
                country_code = "US"
            };


            var payment = new Payment();
            payment.intent = "sale";

            payment.payer = new Payer();
            payment.transactions = new List<Transaction>();

            var t = new Transaction()
            {
                description = req.Description,
                amount = new Amount()
                {
                    total = req.TotalPayment.ToString("N2"),
                    currency = "USD",
                },
            };

            t.item_list = new ItemList();
            t.item_list.items = new List<Item>();
            t.item_list.items.Add(new Item()
                {
                    name = req.Description,
                    quantity = "1",
                    price = req.TotalPayment.ToString("N2"),
                    currency = "USD",
                });
            payment.transactions.Add(t);

            payment.payer.funding_instruments = new List<FundingInstrument>();
            payment.payer.payment_method = "credit_card";

            var fundingInstrument = new FundingInstrument();
            fundingInstrument.credit_card = creditCard;


                payment.payer.funding_instruments.Add(fundingInstrument);

            var pay = payment.Create(token);
            if (req.PaymentOption != PayOption.UsePayPal && pay.state == PayPalStateApproved
                    && pay.transactions.Any() && pay.transactions[0].related_resources.Any()
                    && pay.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale != null
                    && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(pay.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.id))
            {
                resp.TransactionID = pay.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.id;
            }
            else
            {
                resp.Status = Status.Error;
                resp.Messages.Add(new Message { Code = "paypal", Text = pay.state });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var err = CheckPayPalError(ex);
            resp.Messages.Add(new Message { Code = "paypal", Text = String.IsNullOrEmpty(err) ? ex.Message : err });

            resp.Status = Status.Error;
        }

        return resp;
```

Here are the log entries, the first is if Retry is set to > 0, the second is with no retry
2013-08-29 09:41:45,852 [33] DEBUG PayPal.PayPalResource [(null)] User-Agent:PayPalSDK/rest-sdk-dotnet 0.7.3 ;lang=DOTNET;v=4.0.30319.18052;bit=64;os=Windows 7 6.1.7601.65536;
2013-08-29 09:41:45,852 [33] DEBUG PayPal.PayPalResource [(null)] PayPal-Request-Id:a781e6bb-c0b0-4f06-abf8-1202dbc17a59
2013-08-29 09:41:45,920 [33] DEBUG PayPal.Manager.ConnectionManager [(null)] {"intent":"sale","payer":{"payment_method":"credit_card","funding_instruments":[{"credit_card":{"number":"4234567890123456","type":"visa","expire_month":5,"expire_year":2015,"cvv2":"123","first_name":"MIckey","last_name":"Keenan","billing_address":{"line1":"123 Main St","city":"Denver","country_code":"US","postal_code":"80210","state":"CO"},"payer_id":"205"}}]},"transactions":[{"amount":{"currency":"USD","total":"4.75"},"description":"WFS Lunch Order","item_list":{"items":[{"quantity":"1","name":"WFS Lunch Order","price":"4.75","currency":"USD"}]}}]}
2013-08-29 09:41:49,505 [33] ERROR PayPal.Manager.ConnectionManager [(null)] Error Response: {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"2520071cde1ca"}
2013-08-29 09:41:49,506 [33] INFO  PayPal.Manager.ConnectionManager [(null)] Got InternalServerError status code from server
2013-08-29 09:41:49,507 [33] ERROR PayPal.Exception.PayPalException [(null)] Exception in HttpConnection Execute: Stream was not readable.
PayPal.Exception.PayPalException: Exception in HttpConnection Execute: Stream was not readable. ---> System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable.
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream)
   at PayPal.HttpConnection.Execute(String payLoad, HttpWebRequest httpRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Here is the second
   2013-08-29 09:44:27,685 [16] DEBUG PayPal.PayPalResource [(null)] User-Agent:PayPalSDK/rest-sdk-dotnet 0.7.3 ;lang=DOTNET;v=4.0.30319.18052;bit=64;os=Windows 7 6.1.7601.65536;
2013-08-29 09:44:27,686 [16] DEBUG PayPal.PayPalResource [(null)] PayPal-Request-Id:1d5c68e5-4b4b-4876-8bf4-3b9f64d0afb6
2013-08-29 09:44:27,753 [16] DEBUG PayPal.Manager.ConnectionManager [(null)] {"intent":"sale","payer":{"payment_method":"credit_card","funding_instruments":[{"credit_card":{"number":"4234567890123456","type":"visa","expire_month":5,"expire_year":2015,"cvv2":"123","first_name":"MIckey","last_name":"Keenan","billing_address":{"line1":"123 Main St","city":"Denver","country_code":"US","postal_code":"80210","state":"CO"},"payer_id":"205"}}]},"transactions":[{"amount":{"currency":"USD","total":"4.75"},"description":"WFS Lunch Order","item_list":{"items":[{"quantity":"1","name":"WFS Lunch Order","price":"4.75","currency":"USD"}]}}]}
2013-08-29 09:44:28,847 [16] ERROR PayPal.Manager.ConnectionManager [(null)] Error Response: {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"465701e606a56"}
2013-08-29 09:44:28,848 [16] INFO  PayPal.Manager.ConnectionManager [(null)] Got InternalServerError status code from server
2013-08-29 09:44:28,850 [16] ERROR PayPal.Exception.PayPalException [(null)] Exception in HttpConnection Execute
PayPal.Exception.PayPalException: Exception in HttpConnection Execute

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Every test credit card I try gives me an INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR response.  I contacted PayPal support and they referred me to this post on SO  :)

Answer (score 0):

We sometimes see issue with the Test Card 4111xxx in sandbox and are investigating the fix for the same. Hence use the other Test card in sandbox for your testing.

Reg the stream read error, will test the provided code and update back.

Comment: Any update on this?  I would expect either 4111-1111-1111-1111 or 4234-5678-9012-3456 to work in either environment.  But I have customers entering in a CC number that presumably is what is on their card getting the same Stream is not readable...  Could it be that he card is failing some validation (address, zipcode, CVV code, etc...)  but those seem to return valid errors

Comment: Do you still face this issue? I get a correct invalid credit card response for an invalid test card. If you still face the issue please update the comments with the actual JSON request payload without your credentials etc.,

Comment: Yes I am still getting this.  I ran some tests with the SDK downloaded from GIT and was able to get more info... When I make the request the first time, it returns with a Java Read Timeout error... it then tries a retry and I get the Stream was not readable error...  the Real issue is probably the timeout, but the retry does not work in this case...  I added the JSON calls from the log messages...  let me know if that helps...

Comment: Here is part of the read time out error i was talking about <br/> {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","information_link":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"c1d8ba2115c0a","internalCause":["TopLevelMessage: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out","RootCauseMessage: SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out","org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out","\tat

Comment: Yes it was helpful. We are working to get you a fix for the same.

Comment: I'm getting this same error for every test credit card I try.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed in core SDK. Fix is available in branch https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/tree/fix-log4net-stream. Please see https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-dotnet/issues/10 for more details.

Comment: Thanks.  Although I noticed that it no longer works with the Rest API.  The HTTP method has a new enum "HEAD"  so post calls no longer work.  I will need to update the Rest API Code to use the correct DLL.

Answer (score 0):

After talking with PayPal support about this same issue: apparently even in the Sandbox, if a credit card is used too many times it will be blocked.  They suggested trying other fake card numbers, and referred me to this site for generating them:

http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/

Using cards generated there has been working for me.